# youtube player stops when changing to full screen mode

Tags: android, youtube-api

Currently, I am using the youtube api to display youtube videos on my app and it works great, but whenever I change to fullscreen mode the video stops and I need to press the play button to start it again.

It might sound as an unimportant issue, but it is quite important for the purpose of my app, so I would really appreciate any solution.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_player);

        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;


        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);


        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
                .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                        }
                    }
                });

        videoID = getIntent().getStringExtra("video_id");
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        initializeYoutubePlayer();
        String [] temp = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("playlist_order");
        if(temp != null)
            order = Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length);
        else {
            ImageView nextTrackButton = findViewById(R.id.nextTrackButton);
            ImageView lastTrackButton = findViewById(R.id.lastTrackButton);

            nextTrackButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lastTrackButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


    }

    /**
     * initialize the youtube player
     */
    private void initializeYoutubePlayer() {
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.getKey(), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer,
                                                boolean wasRestored) {



                if (!wasRestored) {

                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);


                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID);


                    youTubePlayer.play();

                    youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(true);

                    myYouTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;

                    myYouTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoading() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoaded(String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdStarted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVideoStarted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVideoEnded() {
                            int nextI = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
                                if (order[i].equals(videoID)) {
                                    nextI = i + 1;
                                    break;
                                }

                            }

                            if (nextI >= order.length) {
                                nextI = 0;
                            }

                            videoID = order[nextI];
                            myYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                //print or show error if initialization failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this line to your Manifest file**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        >
    </activity>
```

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution seems to work ... thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API Android has a [YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener). I think you can use that and make it so that the video continues to `play()` when it goes fullscreen.

Comment: Doesn't work. From what I've researched the listener is being called on pressing the full screen button, and in that case the player is still playing and calling play on it will do nothing...
BUT, I did find out that if I disable the automatic behavior of youtube when pressing the full screen button, which is to force landscape mode, I can make the player to keep playing.
The problem is I don't know how to manually force landscape mode in which only the player is shown...